# Google Plus Get Connected Friends

Tags: web, google-plus, google-contacts-api

The List People API stipulates that it is possible to get the list of friends that have your app installed.

https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/list

> collection    string  The collection of people to list.
>
> Acceptable values are: "connected": The list of visible people in the
>   authenticated user's circles who also use the requesting app. This
>   list is limited to users who made their app activities visible to the
>   authenticated user.

I have multiple accounts, all mutually friends with each other. They all have an account in my app, and their Activity visibility for this app is either set to 'My Circles' or 'Public'.

However, when I get the list of `connected` people, only a single friend is returned, for whom I see no difference with the others that are not returned.

I am using the API with an OAuth 2.0 token retrieved using the Web Client-side flow as described here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/ with the scope `plus.login`

Comment: did you solve your problem?